# How to plot wide range data in bi-symmetric logarithmic scale in R?

Tags: r

I have a large dataset need to be displayed in log-scale. But a log transformation could loss the 0 and negative values. I found this figure in literature this kind of symmetric logarithmic scale is just what I need.
[Figure in bi-symmetric logarithmic scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juX8r.png)

The pseudolog10_trans function is R package "ggallin" is not a solution.

I found a solution in Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/292499-how-can-i-plot-negative-value-with-log-scale, how can I plot that in R that include all positive, negative and zero values in log-transformed scale?

Mathematical reference： https://kar.kent.ac.uk/32810/2/2012_Bi-symmetric-log-transformation_v5.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a function to convert to signed log and plot the input with a custom axis. No packages are used.

```
x <- c(-2000, -200, 20, 20, 200, 2000) # test input

signed_log <- function(x) ifelse(x == 0, 0, sign(x) * log(abs(x)))

plot(signed_log(x), yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "o")
b <- c(-1000, -100, -10, 0, 10, 100, 1000)
axis(2, signed_log(b), b)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for the inspiring post! Since I also need to display 1 and -1 values, I make a little change based on your answer: x <- c(-2000, -200, -1, 0, 1, 20, 20, 200, 2000) # test input
signed_log <- function(x) ifelse(x >= -1 & x <= 1, x,  sign(x) * log10(10*abs(x)))
plot(signed_log(x), yaxt = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", type = "o")
b <- c(-1000, -100, -10, -1, 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000)
axis(2, signed_log(b), b)